# android canvas not drawing on touched position

Tags: android, canvas

I am using canvas to make a simple drawing app. I am using onTouchEvent to handle touch event. I am facing a problem on vertical axis drawn point is differentfrom touched position. the vertical separation in between touched position and drawn position increases as I move upward. To make my problem more clear i am attaching screenshot  of my app. [image: screen shot]

Blue line shows actual touched position and red drawn position.

Here is my code
Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Path mPath;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    float pointX;
    float pointY;
    int height;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    int layoutHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        DisplayMetrics dp=getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        WindowManager windowManager=getWindowManager();
        height=windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        int width =windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        layout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bg));
        canvas=new Canvas(bg);
        paint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        mPath=new Path();
        canvas.drawPath(mPath,paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bg,0,0,paint);
    }

    public void clearCanvas(View v) {
        mPath.reset();
        canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        layout.invalidate();
    }
    //override the onTouchEvent
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        pointX = event.getX();
        pointY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.v("TAG"," action down x:"+pointX+" y:"+pointY);
                mPath.moveTo(pointX,pointY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.v("TAG"," actionmove x:"+pointX+" y:"+pointY);
                mPath.lineTo(pointX,pointY);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath,paint);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }
        layout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.vikash.mydrawingapp.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="clear"
        android:onClick="clearCanvas"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @DixitPanchal I have added code. Please help

Comment: Instead of using the `View.getX()`/`View.getY()`, have you considered `View.getRawX()`/`View.getRawY()`? This way, you can get the actual pixel touched, and place a line with that coordinate. As far as I can tell, the issue you are having is that the (x) position clicked related to your screen, is closely related to the (x) of the view, but the (y) clicked is "offset" by the another View, the Title bar.

Comment: @Bonatti I tried getRawX()/getRawY() but no difference observed

Comment: Since your `View` is almost the screen size, you will have difficulties "seing the problem". Change the `Canvas` size to something more rectangular, and the offset will be easily seen, place a "400dp * 800dp" view, and Log the `getX()` and `getY()` values, and compare with the `getRawX()` and `getRawY()`

Comment: @Bonatti I have added bitmap in background of the mainlayout. if I am changing its size it's getting more worse.

Comment: Just like I stated, as well as Nestoraj answer. Use the correct offset for the points, or use Raw position and then scale to your view coordinates/size.

Comment: in this case offset is not fixed Its varying as some function of height. I don't know how to find correct offset. height of notificationbar + toolbar is 135 px. I tried subtracing it from getRawY() but in this case problem just get reverse. I mean separation is more at bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: event.getRawX()

Returns the original raw X coordinate of this event. For touch events on the screen, this is the original location of the event on the screen, before it had been adjusted for the containing window and views.

**UPD:**
I just tried to repeat your app and all works correctly

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <com.example.Test
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Test.java

```
public class Test extends View {

    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    {
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    public Test(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: tired but it didn't help

Comment: yea this works perfect. I have tried this. I was facing problem when i was adding canvas to the background of mainlayout. If I am using this canvas as in your answer it works perfect. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your Canvas X-Axis has the same position of the Screen X-Axis, but your Canvas Y-Axis is offset from Screen Y-Axis (The "MyDrawingApp" bar sets that offset with its height).

What is happening is that when you "getY()" it returns the position of the touch taking as reference the entire screen not your canvas.

One solution is to get the position of the canvas on the screen and minus it to the "getY()" value. Doing this you will get a touch inside of your canvas.

I hope you will understand me, I am not English.

Greetings

Comment: I have already tried subtracting offset. But it doesn't help. In this just reverse of above happens ie difference in canvasY and axisY is more at bottom and less at top